# Finding a function that generates different functions

Tags: functions

I apologize for the ambiguous title, but I wasn't sure how to describe what I mean.

I have 5 lines that fit through 5 points as seen in the picture. That is, each color represents a line through 5 points (the last two values are all the same that's why they overlap at point 4 and 5).

Now, I'm looking for some function with some number of parameters that generates all of these different lines. The number of parameters should be kept as small as possible.

In other words, I vary the value of the parameter(s) of this function and it generates the points of the red line in the picture. Then I change the value of the parameter(s) again in some way and it generates the points of yellow line and so forth.

Ideally, the function is continuous and differentiable; if such a function even exists.

[image]

Here are the y-values for the x-values 1 to 5:

function 1: 1,0.71,0.42,0.14,0 
function 2: 1,1,0.71,0.14,0 
function 3: 1,0.85,0.57,0.14,0 
function 4: 1,0.57,0.28,0.14,0 
function 5: 1,0.42,0.14,0.14,0

For clarity I add an example: Take the following y-values to the x-values 0 to 4:

{{0, 1, 4, 9, 16}, {0., 1.3, 4.6, 9.9, 17.2}, {0., 3.5, 9., 16.5, 
  26.}, {0, 5, 12, 21, 32}, {0, 19, 40, 63, 88}}

These are 5 sets of 5 points. The question is, which function and associated 5 different parameter values produced the set of points.

The answer, in this case, is the function: $$ f(x)=a x + x^2 $$ with parameter values for $ a$ equal to {0, 0.3, 2.5, 4, 18}.

For example, set $ a=0 $, then $$ f(0)=0,f(1)=1^2=1, f(2)=2^2=4, f(3)=3^2=9, f(4)=4^2=16. $$ which results in the first set of 5 points. Setting $a=0.3$ results in the second set of points asf.

NOTE: After adding this example, I'm wondering if this problem can even be solved analytically and instead requires some form of optimization algorithm.

Comment: best you can hope for is a family of functions; a function has a unique image for a point, but here you would need $f(5) = 0.15$ but also $f(5) = 0.3$.

Comment: Please see updated post. I added the exact values. f(5)=0.

Comment: Are you after a practical application or theoretical analysis? There are ways for doing this practically. Also, you provide x-values, but I think these are (x,y) values AND I am not sure they match the points in the graph.

Comment: The functions are determined by the value of two poins, so you can do it with a multivariate function $f:\{green, purple, blue, yellow, red\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $f(colour) =(f_{color}(2), f_{color}(3))$

Comment: @NoChance: I'm more interested in doing this practically. The values provided are the y-values e.g. function 1 (blue): (x,y)->(1,1),(2,0.71),(3,0.42) asf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method (1)**

You can build a table (functin #, x, y). If you are using this in a computer program it will be easy to lookup the values of function#, x-value to get y-value.
This method is limited to the x-values in the table.

**Method (2)**

You can get more information by calculating the line equation of each segment of each line. For the blue line, given the points (note, your exact values may differ, I only want to demonstrate the concept):

$$(x,y): (1,1),(2,0.71),(3,0.42),(4,0.18)$$

Blue Function: For points:$(1,1),(2,0.71)$ the line equation is: $y = -0.29x + 1.29$

Blue Function: For points:$(2,0.71),(3,0.42)$ the line equation is: $y = -0.29x + 1.29$

Blue Function: For points:$(3,0.42),(4,0.18)$ the line equation is: $y = -0.24x + 1.14$

The common segment connects the points (4,0.18), (5,0) so the equation of the line connecting these points is: $y = -0.18x + 0.9$

This allows you to calculate the value of y for any value of x between the end points. For example, for x=2.1 you can use the equation $y=-0.29x + 1.29$$.

You could easily utilize a calculator to help you get the equations for example:[Line Equation Calculator](https://www.calculator.net/slope-calculator.html).

Answer (score 0):

The functions are determined by the value of two poins, so you can do it with a multivariate function $f:\{green, purple, blue, yellow, red\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $f(color) =(f_{color}(2), f_{color}(3))$

Once you know those two points, it's easy to match each pair of values with each line